# combinatoric grouping optimization problem based on time interval overlap, weight constraint, and distance minimization

Tags: algorithm, optimization, grouping, nonlinear-optimization

Let each element be an individual. Consider that an individual is defined such that each individual has a time range, weight, and location.

The goal is to group together individuals whose time ranges overlap while ensuring that, within the group, the sum of the weights of the individuals do not exceed a certain threshold. At the same time, it is desirable to minimize the total distance between the individuals in the group. As many individuals as necessary can be placed into a group as long as the weight constraint is met. Let there be N individuals (assume at most 5000 individuals in a practical implementation).

The goal is to have as many individuals grouped (that is at minimum paired) as possible while minimizing the total distance between individuals in groups. This problem appears to be NP-hard so I am not looking for a global minimum but a good solutions.

For example, consider an example in the discrete time case where there are ten time intervals. [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]. The weight threshold is 4 and the location of the individuals are points on the 1-D line of integers.
Say that we have the following individuals:

```
A: time range: [1, 2, 3] | weight: 1 | location: 1
B: time range: [2, 3, 4] | weight: 2 | location: 2
C: time range: [4, 5, 6] | weight: 2 | location: -3
D: time range: [4, 5, 6] | weight: 3 | location: -3
```

**Note:**

- A and C cannot be grouped because they do not have overlapping time ranges.
- grouping together A and B gives is preferable to grouping together B and C because A and B are closer together.
- C and D cannot be grouped because the sum of their weights exceed 4.
  Does any one have a recommended algorithm for solving a problem like this?

*I've looked at the examples in (Studies in Computational Intelligence 666) Michael Mutingi, Charles Mbohwa (auth.) - Grouping Genetic Algorithms_ Advances and Applications-Springer International Publishing (2017). However, none of the grouping algorithms seem very fitting.*

**Different Ways to Understand / Interpret This Problem:**

*Interpretation 1: Bin-Packing Problem*

The goal is to find a partition of the individuals such that, within each partition, time ranges of all members overlap. The total 'weight' sum of each partition is below a certain threshold (note that no single individual will exceed the weight threshold). The total 'distance' sum (computed by summing the distance derived from each partition) is minimized. As few one individual partitions are formed.

*Interpretation 2:*

See Below

**My Impractical Approach For This Problem**

*Step 1: Defining an individual*

```
Individual:
   Time Range: [2, 3, 4]
   Weight: 2
   Location: -3
```

*Step 2: Finding Potentially Time-Compatible Individuals*

Imagine that a 24-hour day is defined as 24 one-hour bins. Each bin represents one hour. For example, the bin at index 6 represents 6 am. Let's call this the timetable.

We place individuals into these bins based on their time range. For example, If John's time range is [1, 2] and Wilson's time range is [2, 3], then the timetable will be populated as follows:

```
[ [] , [John] , [John, Wilson], [Wilson], [] , ... , [] ]
```

Here, individuals in the same bin could potentially be grouped.

> **OUTDATED**
>
> *Step 3: Generating Viable Groups Based On Weight Constraint*
>
> Let's define the weight limit of a group to be 4.
>
> For each bin in the timetable, we generate groups that meet the weight
>   constraint (the sum of the weights of the individuals is below 4).
>   Note we can skip over the bins with one or fewer individuals. Here,
>   each group has the following characteristics:
>
> ```
> Group:
>    Individuals: [ Person1, Person2, ... ]
>    Weight: INT (computed by summing weight of individuals)
>    Distance: FLOAT (computed by finding distance sum between individuals)
> ```
>
> We take all of the groups we generated and store them together in a
>   list called viable_groups.
>
> *Step 4: Finding the best set of groups*
>
> We optimize the groups / partitioning by finding the set of disjoint
>   groups such that the total distance sum is minimized.
>
> **Problem with this approach**
>
> By step 3, this approach becomes computationally infeasible because we
>   generate all possible groups by enumeration.

**UPDATE:**

*Step 1: New Definition of 'Individual'*

In the beginning, each individual is treated as a singleton group:

```
Group:
   members: [person1]
   time range: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
   weight: 2
   location: -3
```

*Step 2: same as before*

*Step 3: sort time bins by population*

Time bins are sorted by the number of singleton groups in that bin in descending order. After the sort, the time bin with the most number of singleton groups is ranked first.

*Step 4: merge groups until no merge is possible*

Starting with the first time bin, construct a graph such that the nodes are the groups and the edges represent the distance between two groups. An edge exists between two groups only if their weight sum does not exceed the maximum capacity. For example, let the weight threshold be 4 and consider the following singleton groups:

```
group1:
   members: [person1]
   time range: [0, 1, 2]
   weight: 1
   location: -3

group2:
   members: [person2]
   time range: [0, 1, 2, 3]
   weight: 2
   location: 0

group3:
   members: [person3]
   time range: [0, 1]
   weight: 3
   location: 1
```

Notes that out of the 3 possible edges, the following edges exist:

```
group1 -- 3 -- group2
group1 -- 4 -- group3
```

This is because group2 - group3  exceeds the weight threshold of 4.

Now we find the edge with the smallest value and merge the two end nodes. After merging the two nodes, we recompute the edges based on the new set of nodes available, and we repeat until no edges exist.

In terms of the above example, we would merge group1 and group2 to obtain:

```
group12:
   members: [person1, person2] (union of members)
   time range: [0, 1, 2] (intersection of time ranges)
   weight: 3 (sum of weights)
   location: 1.5 (center between two locations)

group3:
   members: [person3]
   time range: [0, 1]
   weight: 3
   location: -3
```

Now, if we recompute the edges, we see that no edges exist. Thus, we are done with the first time bin.

Next, we remove all of the singleton groups that have members that overlap with the members in subsequent time bins. For example, in this case, if we find either group1, group2, or group3 in the subsequent, we remove those groups.

we repeat the merging process we performed on the first time bins.

We repeat this until the last time bin.

*This is my approach so far, and I realize it's not the most efficient. Does anyone have recommendations for improvements? Please let me know in the comments if any part of the explanation is unclear!*

Answer (score 0):

> The goal is to have as many individuals grouped (that is at minimum
>   paired) as possible while minimizing the total distance between
>   individuals in groups.

Since your goal is to group as many individuals as possible you do not have to compare all groups but only those set of groups that allow for the highest number of grouped individuals before you do any further comparisons on distance.

If you take each bin as a set and try to find the biggest union of them and there is a single biggest one you could check it now for feasibility. If it's not feasible you would have to try the second biggest etc.

A person's weight must be one or higher? If so and you know your weight limit certain pairings might be more attractive and if you are okay with a more approximating approach you could apply a greedy algorithm to each bin (to fit the weight best) and then apply greedy to your coverage problem next.

Basically you would try to group as many individuals after selecting efficient yet feasible time slot allocations and only then in case there is more than one option you would compare these options for more lower overall distance.

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_coverage_problem

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I've updated my current progress after discussing with some of my colleagues and drawing from your suggestion. Do you have any recommendations for improving my updated approach?

Comment: @jxing8 It is a greedy approach which makes sense to lower the complexity. A graph solution might be just one option for a structure on which you apply the greedy though. What I am unsure of would be why you want to group the individuals first that result in the smallest sum. Are you sure that is the right way if you goal is to group as many individuals as possible? Also your new individual definition seems to lack the time table information. Are you planing on converting the individual in the running program from old to new? Besides that I like the new data structure for groups.

Comment: I group the individuals connected by the edge that has the lowest value because those individuals are the closest together in distance. I am not certain that this is the right way to group as many individuals as possible. After choosing a greedy approach, what I am finding is no longer the global maximum in terms of the number of individuals grouped. Thus, I am trying to find a good balance instead at this point. And thank you for pointing out the type in my group definition, I have now fixed it.

Comment: @jxing8 Glad I could be of help. I've been thinking about possible pairings and with your approach you would need to make sure that after pairing 2s together with 1s that the remaining 1s would go with free 3s instead of being added to groups of [2,1]. Since [3,1] and [2,1,1] have the same weight yet the first ensures the grouping of an extra individual the first pairing is preferable. A same problem exists for pairings [1,1,1] vs [2,1] too. Yet this problem wouldn't arise if you would be greedy from heavy to light instead of light to heavy.

Comment: right now in my approach, I am merging two groups first if they are the closest together compared to any other pairs of groups. I guess with your recommendation (thank you for the great suggestion btw), I can think of two ways to modify my approach: 1. I could keep doing what I am doing, but now when two edges have a similar distance value, I group together the pair with the heaviest member first. 2. I start with the heaviest group and merge it with with closest neighbor, then I move on to the next heaviest group.

Comment: On a note, I do not want to group as many people together as possible (by completely prioritizing grouping as many as possible). Distance is also an important parameter the members in the same group should not be too spread out in relative location.

Comment: @jxing8 In my head going from heavy to light should be less "work" than checking for equality and on equality selecting the heavier member. Also if like you said distance is of any matter to you, you will need to define a kind of ratio between number of grouped individuals and distance because those fulfilling these two priorities at the same time should be close to impossible.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll think a bit more about the balance I want between grouping together more people and minimizing distance. Though I want to group together as many people as possible, having individuals too far apart in groups is problematic in the practical application of this algorithm.